# How to scrape data from WMS

Tags: qgis, wms, getfeatureinfo

I'm struggling with a problem which I'd like to solve. In general, when I use the "identify" tool on a WMS I can see, in the debug panel, the BBOX of the feature I clicked on.

I suppose that it's possible to do a massive GETFEATUREINFO on the underlying layer in order to scrape features' BBOX and the data in the exposed fields.

Here's the WMS link: https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php

Can someone try to suggest a starting point to achieve the goal?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: You would be better off using a WFS endpoint - try contacting the owners of the site to see if you can download their data in a better way

Comment: @IanTurton, it's not possible to contact the owner. It's a governative organization and those are cadastral data.
Someone did it, I know it for sure. It's possible to retrieve the BBOX of every single feature and then populate them with attributes scraped from the source.
Here is the video, showing the result: https://youtu.be/ONP8UQcwpqg

Comment: Don't. This is an abuse of the service.

Comment: government organisations are the easiest to contact - they (almost) always fill out the contact section of the servers.

Comment: You can't do a massive GetFeatureInfo request; a GetFeatureInfo request is a request for feature or features at a point location, a pixel in the GetMap request generated image.   You could potentially iterate across all pixels in an image with multiple requests but you'll likely end up with duplicated data.

Comment: Contact details are provided in the GetCapabilities response for the service: https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

Answer (score 2):

From the INSPIRE geoportal, see the Italy datasets and services here: https://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/results.html?country=it&view=details&theme=none , you can search for the data, and then find out whether they offer WFS services.

These are the INSPIRE services for the "cp" theme, which is "Cadastral parcels": https://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/results.html?country=it&view=details&theme=cp .

The contact information can be seen in the service metadata at https://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/download_details.html?view=downloadDetails&resourceId=%2FINSPIRE-c22038a7-4e03-11e8-a459-52540023a883_20220505-152002%2Fservices%2F1%2FPullResults%2F1181-1200%2Fdatasets%2F17&expandedSection=metadata. I am not copying them here in case they change in the future.